# Received no data in response when loading asset bundle in unity 2019.2.9

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, assetbundle

Recently I have converted my **Unity 2019.1.0** project int**o Unity 2019.2.9** and it is a WebGL project. In the project I am using asset bundle and here is the snippet to load the bundle:

```
 IEnumerator DependancyAssetBundleLoader()
    {

        www = UnityWebRequestAssetBundle.GetAssetBundle(bundleURLForDependency);
       // www.chunkedTransfer = false;

        yield return www.SendWebRequest();
        AssetBundle bundleDependancy = ((DownloadHandlerAssetBundle)www.downloadHandler).assetBundle;

        if (www.error != null)
        {

            //Debug.LogError("assetBundleURL : " + bundleURLForDependency);
            Debug.LogError("response code : " + www.responseCode);

            Debug.LogError("www error : " + www.error);
            www.Dispose();
            www = null;
            yield break;

        }
    }
```

I don't know what went wrong with the asset bundle loading and now I am getting this error:

> Received no data in response

I logged the response code and it is 0.

Comment: In general you should check for errors before doing `AssetBundle bundleDependancy = ...`. Also use `using(var www = ...){ ... }` and so you don't have to call `Dispose` "manually". Is the URL you pass in correct?

Comment: Yes it is correct url. I can download asset bundle from the browser using the url. It is happening after conversion to unity 2018.2.9